# Clustering a MERN app in a 4 Cores machine

Tags: node.js, mern

I am trying to cluster a MERN app in a 4 cores server and I am stuck after I have declared the cluster and numCPUs. How should I go about it clustering a MERN app? Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any helps. Thanks again.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors =  require("cors");
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const connectDB = require("./dbconfig/dbconfig");
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const path = require('path');
const productRoute = require('./routes/products')
dotenv.config()
connectDB()
const cluster = require('cluster')
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length

    const port = process.env.PORT || 5000    

    var whitelist = ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:5000'];
    app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: whitelist }));    

    app.use(cookieParser())
    app.use(morgan('dev'))    

    app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}))
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))

    app.use('/api', productRoute)    

    app.use(express.static(path.join("frontend" ,"build")))    

    app.get("*",(req,res) => {
            res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "frontend","build","index.html"))
        })

    app.listen(port,() => {
        console.log(`Listening to part ${port}...`)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors =  require("cors");
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const connectDB = require("./dbconfig/dbconfig");
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const path = require('path');
const productRoute = require('./routes/products')
dotenv.config()
connectDB()
const cluster = require('cluster')
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000   

var whitelist = ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:5000'];
    app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: whitelist }));    

    app.use(cookieParser())
    app.use(morgan('dev'))    

    app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}))
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))

    app.use('/api', productRoute)    

    app.use(express.static(path.join("frontend" ,"build")))    

    app.get("*",(req,res) => {
            res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "frontend","build","index.html"))
        })

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        // Create a worker
        cluster.fork();
    }
} else {
    // Workers share the TCP connection in this server
    // All workers use this port
    app.listen(8080);
}
```

You can also add the error handling if the worker is closed. For more details, you can check [here](https://stackabuse.com/setting-up-a-node-js-cluster/).